# Finding the optimal sum of a 2D array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem statement goes like this:

Given an N x M array of (nonnegative) integers, find the optimal value of each column in the array, taking into account free rows. 
A free row is anything in the range of [prevOld, prevNew]
Free rows are given starting values of:
prevOld = 0 
prevNew = 0
so at the first step, only row 0 is free. If an element lies in a free row, it incurs no penalty.

If an element is not in a free row, then the penalty incurred is 2 * distance to closest free row - (e.g if free rows are [1,3] and our element is in row 5 then the element loses 2*(5-3) value. But if the element was in row 2, then no pentalty is incurred since 1 <= 2 <= 3

Once an element has been selected, free rows are updated as such:
prevOld = prevNew
prevNew = row of selected element
So if we begin with [x,y] and choose element in row z, then for the next column, free rows are now [y,z]

We are asked to solve this using an dynamic programming algorithm.
I am having a hell of a time coming up with a recurrence relation for this problem. I originally tried an algorithm that chooses the maximum element in a column based on a "real" value given the free rows, but this doesn't take into account the fact that sometimes we want to choose a lower value in our current column for a higher value in the next column. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Sample input/output (no input/output was given, so putting this together from instructions):

Input: 3 x 3 array

4 5 7

7 8 7

1 9 10

First column is 4 7 1 and our starting rows are prevOld = 0 and prevNew = 0, [0,0]
so the 0th row is the only free row, with that, the "real" values of the first column are: 4 5 -3

4 is row 0, so it is free therefore its value is not affected

7 is in row 1, which is 1 away from the closest free row 0, so it loses 2*1 value, so 7 has a "real" value of 5

1 is in row 2, which is 2 away from the closest row, so it loses 2*2 value, so 1 has a "real" value of -3

With these real values we would select 7 (row 1) as our choice. Now we update prevOld and prevNew

prevOld = prevNew

prevNew = 1 (because we selected row 1)

so now we have [0,1] as the free rows and we move onto the next column: 5 8 9

Skipping ahead: real values of this column are

5 (row 0 is free, no loss)

8 (row 1 is free, no loss)

7 (row 2 is 1 away from the closest free row, so it loses 2*1 value)

so we choose 8 (row 1) and update prevOld and prevNew again:

prevOld = prevNew

prevNew = 1 (selected row)

free rows are now [1,1] for the final column: 7 7 10

real values are: 5 7 8, so we choose 8 and were done

Output is: 1 1 2 (the rows we selected in each column), total: 21 (total of the "real" values we selected in the rows)

Comment: Can you please provide an example with input, output and an explanation of how the output was achieved?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added some sample input along with steps on how we get the sample output

Comment: First column is 4 5 1?

Comment: Sorry fixed now.